# Take a screenshot of just an image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, screenshot

I've an image view

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

which I want to screenshot. The code I have is taking the whole screen. I've looked at the other answers on here and still can't work it out as I don't want to designate a size, I just need the whole of the image view as a screenshot.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line

`CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

with

`CGRect rect = view.bounds;`

Hope this will work as you want.

Comment: It's still taking the whole screen not just the image view.

Comment: Its working for me. May you have done something wrong or could not explain your problem properly.